# SyntaxError: invalid syntax が出力

Tags: python, python3

初歩的な質問になるかと思うのですが、解決の糸口が掴めず質問します。
vncdotool(https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool) というモジュールを使用し、VNC経由で接続先のスクリーンショットを取得したいと考えています。
上記URL、Quick Startに記載のスクリーンショットを取得する例を試そうと考えたのですが、
IPアドレスの箇所を対象に構文エラーが出力。解決できずにおります。

ダブルコーテーションで囲んでみるも、同様のエラーがでています。
どなたかお助けをば。

[image: invalid syntax]

[image: pip lists]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vncdo -s vncservername capture screen.png` というのはコマンドラインツールの使い方です。

「Python のライブラリ」と「Python で作られたコマンドラインツール」を区別してください。Python のライブラリは Python のプログラムとして使うもの、コマンドラインツールは Bash や cmd.exe などコマンドラインの上で使うものです。

`pip install` でパッケージをインストールすると、ライブラリがインストールされることも、コマンドラインツールがインストールされることもあります。sibson/vncdotool の場合、両方インストールされます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
なるほど……仰るとおり、cmd にてvncdo と入力したところ、問題なく実行されました。ご指摘の点、区別がついておりませんでしたので、とてもありがたいコメントでした。ありがとうございました。